# Fast hash function with unique hashes

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I'm writing a disk cache where filenames are the keys. The keys can be longer than the max filename length, so they need to be hashed. What are some fast hash functions with extremely low probability of collisions (so that I can ignore it)?

Basically, I'm looking for a faster alternative to MD5 with no security requirenments.

(Platform = Android, language = Java.)

Comment: 1) Why must it be fast? 2) you cannot ignore collisions. 3) _birthday paradox_

Comment: Which programming language are you using?Doesn't it has a hash table? Do you think there is a problem using its hash function to use the filename as the key?

Comment: @wildplasser 1) faster is better 2) I can if they're very unlikely

Comment: @Cratylus Java, I could use String.hashCode() but I'm not confident that collisions are unlikely enough.

Comment: 1) the cost of calling a hash function is _nothing_ compared to the cost of reading a page from disk. 2) an additional memcmp() or strcmp() has a about the same cost as a hash function, typically one or a few ticks per byte. 3) do the math.

Comment: @fhucho: You could create your own object and override hashCode with some additional fields if you think that this will have better distribution.

Comment: "I can if they're very unlikely" - common misconception, @wildplasser is right. The probability of a collision existing exceeds 0.99 by the time you've generated `3*sqrt(key_space_size)` hashes. If the `key_space_size` is a million, it's nearly a dead certainty you'll have a collision within the first 3000 hashes.

Comment: @wildplasser 1) On Android, the first MD5 hash after app start takes 30 ms. Reading from disk can be under 5 ms. 3) Are you saying that I can create e.g. MD5 collisions by accident?

Comment: BTW: IIRC android is based on a linux kernel. Linux has hash tables +LRU built in for filesystem acces. For disk buffers+ inode cache + directory entry cache. So, in fact the OP is trying to implement double buffering. For the case where the key is too large to fit in a dirname/filename, _any_ sane hash function (FNV,Bernstein,Jenkins,shift+XOR) (plus additional memcpy) would suffice.

Comment: @pjs but `3*sqrt(MD5_key_space_size)` is huge. I'm looking for a faster MD5 wihout the security requirenments.

Comment: @fhucho Okay. I got the impression you were trying to create your own hash, possibly on a small key-space, to achieve speed.

Comment: How many items do you intend to keep in the cache? That number is more or less related to (the square of) the hash key space you want to use.

Comment: @wildplasser I recon about 10000 is the upper bound.

Comment: In that case: anything goes. Use plain 32bit FNV or Jenkins, or roll your own (and test)

Comment: @wildplasser 32bit hash still has non-ignorable possibility of a collision. My cache currently uses MD5 and assumes that collisions never happen. So I'm basically looking for faster and not-necessarily-secure MD5.

Comment: @Cratylus I'll probably do something like that. E.g. split the key to halves, hashCode() each half and concat the hashes.

Comment: @fhucho : as I said in my second comment: after finding a matching entry with the same hash value, you can always perform a plain compare of the key, using strcmp() or memcmp(); that will separate the false positives from the true positives.

Comment: @wildplasser compare the key with what? The filename is the hashed key and file content is the cache value.

Comment: How much data are you hashing for this to matter? Even an ARM can hash >100 MByte/s using MD5.

Comment: xxHash has an internal state of 128 bits, which is the same size as MD5. It currently merge them to create a final 32-bits hash, but it's not difficult to change the final step to create 64-bits hashes, or 128-bits hashes. 128-bits is probably what you are looking for : negligible enough probability of collision, even with several billions files.

Answer (score 6):

if your hash is uniformly distributed then you can calculate the size of the hash (in bits) that you need from the approx number of files you expect to handle before a collision.  basically, because of the birthday paradox, it's twice the number of bits.

so, for example, if you are happy with a collision after a million files then you need a has that is about 40 bits log (2 * log2(1e6)).

conversely, if a hash is N bits, then it's good for 2^(N/2) files without collision (more or less).

there are many fast hashes.  for example, [xxhash](https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/) is a 64 bit hash, so is good for about 4,000,000,000 files.  [google's fast-hash](https://code.google.com/p/fast-hash/) is another.

if you want more than 64bits (more than ~4 billion files before a collision) then you can either use a hash with a larger output or join two 64bit hashes together (one hash from the original file and one with it modified in some way (eg prefixed with a space)).

Answer (score 0):

The google guava library has different fast hash implementations:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#murmur3_128%28%29